# How can I run two of the same syndication scripts on the same page?

Tags: javascript

I have a script obtained from our Sharp dealership to display machines on our website.  When I add it twice with a different model (data-name) it only runs the first and drops off the image after it flashes on the page.  I did try changing the div id of the second but it did not work.

Sample 1:

```
<script src='http://siica.sharpusa.com/DesktopModules/X3.Sharp.ProductCatalog/js/GetProduct.js' type='text/javascript' data-type='MFPs' data-name='MX-3050N'></script>
<div id='sharp-widget'></div>
```

Sample 2:

```
<script src='http://siica.sharpusa.com/DesktopModules/X3.Sharp.ProductCatalog/js/GetProduct.js' type='text/javascript' data-type='MFPs' data-name='MX-3070N'></script>
<div id='sharp-widget'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing that Mike.

Comment: You should ask the people that write your widget.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code you used above, you can't, at least not without some kind of workaround.

The javascript you used expect explicitly a item with id "sharp-widget", but HTML doesn't validate repeated ids, so jQuery wont render it.

My suggestion would be to contact the provider of script to let you pass the id as a parameter or, if it's not possible, do some workaround like adding an iframe to the second one, something like:

```
<script src='http://siica.sharpusa.com/DesktopModules/X3.Sharp.ProductCatalog/js/GetProduct.js' type='text/javascript' data-type='MFPs' data-name='MX-3050N'></script>
<div id='sharp-widget'></div>

<iframe src="./inc.html" style="width: 100%; border: none">

</iframe>
```

And `inc.html`

```
<script src='http://siica.sharpusa.com/DesktopModules/X3.Sharp.ProductCatalog/js/GetProduct.js' type='text/javascript' data-type='MFPs' data-name='MX-3050N'></script>
<div id='sharp-widget'></div>
```